# Seek a Java advanced tree component (include Windowless Richedit Control function)

Tags: java, tree, richedit-control

I love BooguNote very much (it's a Sharp tool for collecting and organizing information scraps) But what a pity it just run under windows currently.

I tried to build a Java version for BooguNote so I can run it under linux (first step: I want to just make a simple BooguViewer ) since I'm not very familiar with so huge Java libraries, so I ask for help who know the suitable Java tree component in this case.

My requirement is this:

it's not an usual tree component, as you can check from the BooguNote's screenshot as below: 
http://boogu.me/en.jpg

Usual tree is used as an outline, but in BooguNote, **tree node** was **used as a content container** at the same time - you can even save a huge text in it! (I heard the author said in the forum before he used "Windowless Richedit Control" technology).

Any advices are welcome, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This **[Oracle tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)** tells you how to create graphical user interfaces (GUIs) for applications and applets, using the Java Swing components.

Start with the **[Using Swing Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)** tutorial.  Go through the following top-level lessons:

- Using Top-Level Containers
- The JComponent Class
- Using Text Components

Go through the following component lessons:

- How to Make Frames (Main Windows)
- How to Use Panels
- How to Use Trees

The Swing components that you want to use to make a viewer are JFrame, JPanel, and JTree.

Comment: Thanks, Gilbert Le Blanc: I'll have a try!